# Why is q_table[state, action] giving me an index error?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to make a reinforcement learning model using GYM library by OpenAI and using the Frozen Lake environment initialized as:

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1")
```

While coding the q-learning algorithm, I am running into index error.

I initially tried the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
import gym

# Create the FrozenLake environment
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1')

# Set the hyperparameters
num_episodes = 10000
max_steps_per_episode = 100
learning_rate = 0.8
discount_rate = 0.95
exploration_rate = 1.0
max_exploration_rate = 1.0
min_exploration_rate = 0.01
exploration_decay_rate = 0.001

# Initialize the Q-table
action_space_size = env.action_space.n
state_space_size = env.observation_space.n
q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))

# Create a list to hold the rewards for each episode
rewards_all_episodes = []

# Q-learning algorithm
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    # Reset the environment
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    rewards_current_episode = 0
    
    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):
        # Exploration-exploitation trade-off
        exploration_rate_threshold = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
        if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate:
            # Exploitation (taking the biggest Q-value for this state)
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state,:])
        else:
            # Exploration (random action)
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        
        # Take the chosen action and observe the new state and reward
        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        
        # Update the Q-table using the Q-learning formula
        q_table[state, action] = (1 - learning_rate) * q_table[state, action] + \
                                 learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(q_table[new_state, :]))
        
        state = new_state
        rewards_current_episode += reward
        
        if done == True:
            break
    
    # Decay the exploration rate for the next episode
    exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + \
                       (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate * episode)
    
    # Append the rewards for this episode to the list
    rewards_all_episodes.append(rewards_current_episode)

# Print the rewards for all episodes
print("Rewards per episode:")
print(rewards_all_episodes)

# Print the Q-table
print("\nQ-table:")
print(q_table)
```

This gave me the error in `env.step()` saying `too many values to unpack`

I then changed it to `new_state, rewards, done, truncate, info` which shifted the error to an index error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I have tried ChatGPT but can't seem to find any answer. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

`env.reset()` returns 2 elements in new versions of gym, making your `state` a tuple that crashes numpy indexing. Either add an additional underscore to the result of `reset` call or downgrade your gym version. With `gym=0.21.0` your initial code works.

P.S. I advise you also to:

- recondisder using such a high `learning_rate`
- check for all-zero Q-values for the given state and if true, use a random action to encourage the exploration

Answer (score 0):

Your state is a numpy array and you're trying to use it to access an index in the q-table which is a 2-d array.

```
q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))
...

q_table[state, action] = ...
```

Solution is to find a way to get an index of that state from the list of possible observation spaces in the env.